# How to add items to neighbours' lists of an agentset that hatches another one?

Tags: netlogo

I currently have one agentset(`breed1`) hatching another agentset(`breed2`). What I would like is to edit the `breed2` (`attribute1` and `attribute2`), then add the edited item (called `item` in the hatch) to the lists of the `breed1`'s neighbours.

EDITED: 
Working on the code after Wade Schuette's answer, I wrote the following

```
breed [people person]
breed [items item_1]


people-own
[
  my-list
  attribute1
  attribute2 
]

items-own
[
  selected
  attribute1
  attribute2
]

to setup
  clear-all

   ;; make turtles to test
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [1 2 3 ] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [ ] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [22 33 ] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list ["a" "b" "c"] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [3  4 5 ] ] 

    ;; make a network
  ask people [ create-links-with other people ]


    reset-ticks
end

to go

  let picked nobody
  let neighbours nobody

ask one-of people 
  [
    set attribute1 random-float 1
    set attribute2 random-float 1

    hatch-items 1 [
      set selected picked
      let this-item self 
      ask myself[
        print (word "turtle "  self " has item " this-item " with attribute1 " attribute1 "and attribute2 " attribute2) 
      set my-list lput this-item my-list
        show my-list
      ]
    ask link-neighbors [ print (word "Person "  who " has this my-list " my-list) 
      set attribute1 (attribute1 + random-float 1)
      set attribute2 (attribute2 + 3)
      set my-list lput this-item my-list
      print (word "added item " this-item " with attribute1 " attribute1 " with attribute2 " attribute2)
      show my-list
      ]
  ]
  ]

  tick

end
```

As you can see, my difficulties are in considering the turtle's neighbours and in updating the information (attribute1 and 2) of the item that I want to add in their lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make two changes to get your code to work.
Move the close-bracket ( ] ) for the hatch statements up BEFORE you try to ask for link-neighbors. Right now, you're asking for link-neighbors for the hatched agent, not the one that called it, so it finds none and fails silently.

If you do that, you get an error about this-item being undefined.  That's because you declared it inside hatch code, so it goes away when hatch code closes.   To fix that, declare this-item just before you call the hatch code ( let this-item "") works fine, but be sure to use LET not SET.

Then later, when updating linked neighbors,  you only need to SET it, because you've already declared it.

I think with those changes it will work.  Here's what I got to work.  I put it many debugging xprint statements and set global verbose? to true to activate them, as I mentioned earlier. Doing all these print statements revealed the problem where link-neighbors suddenly appeared to disappear -- that's how I located the bug.

Set global verbose? to false in setup to deactivate them and get clean output.

```
globals [ 
  verbose?   ;; to turn on debugging statements
]

breed [people person]
breed [items item_1]


people-own
[
  my-list
  attribute1
  attribute2 
]

items-own
[
  selected
  attribute1
  attribute2
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set verbose? true  ;; true means printa lot of stuff

   ;; make turtles to test
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [1 2 3 ] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [ ] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [22 33 ] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list ["a" "b" "c"] ] 
   create-people 1 [ set my-list [3  4 5 ] ] 

    ;; make a network
  ask people [ create-links-with other people ]

  ;; ADDED next 2 lines
  xprint (word "Created this many links in setup: "  count links)  
  ask person 0 [

    let fastcount count link-neighbors
    xprint ( word "In setup,   person " who " has this many links " fastcount ) 
  ]


    reset-ticks
end

to go

  let picked nobody
  let neighbours nobody


  ask one-of people with [ who = 0 ]
  [ 
    let fastcount count link-neighbors
    xprint ( word "Entering ask-person,   person " who " has this many links " fastcount ) 

    set attribute1 random-float 1
    set attribute2 random-float 1

    xprint ( word "Before hatch-items, we have this...")
    xprint (word "turtle "  self " has no item hatched, " 
        " with attribute1 " precision attribute1 2 " and attribute2 " precision attribute2 2) 
    let this-item 0   ;; this was down inside hatch-items, so it evaporated when 
                            ;; finishing hatch-items, causing a problem
                            ;; DECLARE it up here, then SET it inside hatch-items
    hatch-items 1 [
      set selected picked
      set this-item self   ;; this was down here inside hatch-items, move it up 4 lines

     xprint ( word "confirming this-item value is: " this-item )

      ask myself[

      xprint ( word "inside hatch-items ,  inside ask-myself, we have this...")
      xprint (word "turtle "  self " has item " this-item 
       " with attribute1 " precision attribute1 2 " and attribute2 " precision attribute2 2) 

      set my-list lput this-item my-list
       xprint ( word  "hatched item now has my-list = "    my-list )

      ] ;; end of ask myself

    ];;; <====== you want to close context of hatch-items up here, not down below
     ;;; so that ask link-neighbors will work



       ;; ADDED THIS NEXT LINES FOR DEBUGGING  
       xprint "we are done with ask myself,  but still inside hatch-items"
       set fastcount count link-neighbors
       xprint ( word "After ask myself, but still inside hatch-items,   person " who " has this many links " fastcount )  
       xprint ( " the code posted in the revised question failed here")
       xprint ( " PERSON should be person 0  , link count should be 4 ")
       xprint ( " SO ASK  LINK-NEIGHBORS WIll fail !!!")


    xprint " asking link-neighbors to update their lists now"

    ask link-neighbors [ print (word "Person "  who " has this my-list " my-list) 
      set attribute1 (attribute1 + random-float 1)
      set attribute2 (attribute2 + 3)
      set my-list lput this-item my-list
      xprint (word "added item " this-item " with attribute1 " attribute1 " with attribute2 " attribute2)
      show my-list
      ]
;;] ;; closes context of hatch-items,  try closing hatch-items before asking link-neighbors

  ]

  tick

end

to xprint [ stuff ]
  if verbose? [ print stuff ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Wade, when I print the list I am getting the following items: [0 0 (76)]. Do you know why there are values equal to 0?

Comment: I have no idea why there are values equal to zero.  Can you post the actual code you are running that produces those values?

Answer (score 1):

Minor **typo**: one of your methods uses in-link-neighbors and one uses link-neighbors. Unless you want to exclude outbound links, I think you want link-neighbors.

Basically, one **design question** you are asking is whether it's better to find the set of the caller's link-neighbors before hatching and save that in an attribute,  or to find them locally at the time of hatching and forget the list after hatching.  I haven't tried your code, but I think both methods would work.   If the set of links is static, you could find it once, store it, and not bother finding it again every time you hatch a new agent, and save some time. If the set of links is dynamic, you need to look it up every time anyway, so there is no point in saving it in an attribute.

You ask **how to validate** the code.   I have no idea what either of your suggestions mean so I'll answer the general case.  These are probably steps that you could do, and should do, before posting here, to fix all that you can fix by yourself.

**Rule #1:  Start simple, and get that much working before adding complexity.**

Your code already violates Rule #1.  You set two attributes when you could be testing with only one.   What if the second attribute code causes an error that confuses your checking that the overall logic is working.  For that matter, start testing with zero attributes.  Comment out that code and add it back in gradually, checking again at each step.

**Rule #2:  Take small steps.**

Confirm that the code works with only one agent before adding more agents. Make one pass of the "go" step and stop to test.  Get that much perfect before moving on to a second step. Etc.

We can all dream of the day when NetLogo has a real debugger that lets you step through the code one statement at a time, or set break-points. But it doesn't.  By the time the go step is over and a "stop" takes effect, you've lost context. Local variables have  evaporated and can't be checked.  The "stack" of nested calls is lost.

The only way I know of to see the dynamic details in context is to either set new global variables, which is messy,  or make heavy use of embedded "print" statements.

You could also insert an **error statement** to cause a run-time error, examine the calling stack, and have a chance to take a breath and look at the output at that point.

```
error " here is the calling stack, halting execution entirely here."
```

Or, you can use a **user-message statement** to cause the code to pause to let you know that something has changed, or that a condition that never should occur (!) has now occurred. This gives you the nice options of "halt" or continuing to run as if nothing happened.

```
if x > 5 [ user-message " Alert -- X is over 5!! " ]
```

**Other reviewers,  chime in here and share other ways to do this!**

The most useful print statements I've found label several variables of interest and identify where they are executed so you can tell them apart in the output. Example for looking at 3 variables x,y, and z:

```
 print ( word "In step 3,  x = " x " y = " y " z = " z )"
```

It would be great if there was a way to toggle visibility of these statements in the editor, but there isn't.  You can at least toggle whether the statement runs or is skipped by adding a global variable, say "verbose?" and changing the print statements to take advantage of it. ( see below )

Then you can turn on or turn off printing all of these statements at once, as opposed to commenting them out, or worse, deleting them.    In general, don't delete them, because someday you will need to modify and re-validate the code, and you'll need these back again to confirm that the modifications are doing what you want them to do and didn't break something new.  Good "print" statements are worth their weight in gold and worth effort to get in place.

Here's a nice way to have selective printing. Declare a new command called "xprint" that only prints when the global variable "verbose?" is true.  You can set it once in setup, or modify in go mid-stream,  or set verbose? true  or false in the Command Center you step through code.

Then you can use "xprint" instead of "print" where you want to be able to toggle printing or no printing.

```
 xprint ( word "In step 3,  x = " x " y = " y " z = " z )"
```

**That really lowers the cost of having lots of print statements in your code, so it really simplifies the process of verifying code and re-verifying it later.**

```
;; This shows how to use a global variable to turn on or off print statements,
;; which you might want to use while developing and testing code

globals [
  verbose?   ;; true means print lots of things,  false means don't print them
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set verbose? true  ;; or false, whatever.  You can also use the Command Center
                     ;; to set this true or false in the middle of a run
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let x random 10         ;; just for illustrating how this works
  xprint (word "At tick " ticks " x = " x )
  tick
end

to xprint [ stuff ]
  if  verbose? [ print stuff ]
end
```

Comment: One other general trick verifying code is to decide what condition SHOULD be true at some point in the code,  then insert an if-else to test whether that condition is ACTUALLY true, and if not,  trigger an error message.    Or you could use output-print or file-print to send a message to an output area on the screen specific for debugging, or to a permanent log file in your file system.  If you are running a formal test-plan, you may want to log conditions that ARE true as well as catching those that are not true, to confirm that you have tested that use-case.

Comment: In general, here's a useful "30 best practices for software development and testing" document; https://opensource.com/article/17/5/30-best-practices-software-development-and-testing     and a larger-context to thinking about testing: https://csse.usc.edu/TECHRPTS/1979/usccse79-501/usccse79-501.pdf

Comment: Specific to NetLogo,  here's the style guide https://ccl.northwestern.edu/courses/mam2005/styleguide.htm  and guidelines for developing visualizations: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/papers/ABMVisualizationGuidelines/ABM%20Visualization-JASSS.html

Comment: If you're testing a model that will be very expensive if it has bugs that only show up after you release it, the US FDA has guidelines that are very comprehensive and think about things you probably never considered.  https://www.fda.gov/media/73141/download

Comment: My mistake about in-link and link-neighbors. It was a typo. I tried what you have suggested and I totally agree with you. I tried to run the code and see what happens step by step, printing on the observer dashboard the results. The code works, but I have not been able to print all the neighbours of the selected turtle and see if the item was added or not to their lists. This is what I was trying to ask you, as I would like to check if the code can work or not. However, my difficulties are in considering and defining the neighbours of the turtle (myself).

Comment: a.rimbaud -- ok, see my next answer

Comment: Thank you Wade. I edited the question, working on the code you shared. As you can see, my difficulties are mainly in considering the turtle's neighbours and in changing the values of attribute1 and attribute2 before adding the new item to their lists.

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment to the first answer:

> The code works, but I have not been able to print all the neighbours
>   of the selected turtle and see if the item was added or not to their
>   lists. .... However, my difficulties are in
>   considering and defining the neighbours of the turtle (myself).

Can you explain what difficulties you are having?  Can we pick an easier example to work with?   Is the problem you are having with what agent is meant by the word "myself" and "self" depending on how deeply you are nested in ask-whoever calls?

Here's some easier code to start from. Can you create the problem with this code?

By the way, if you are an ask loop within another ask loop,  the keyword "myself" will be defined and you can use

```
 print (word "At point 3, self = " self ", and myself = " myself)
```

to see who is who.   I don't know how to test whether "myself" exists, since if it doesn't this throws an error -- testing = nobody doesn't work and is-agent? doesn't work if myself doesn't exist.  Anyone? How can you tell if myself exists?

Anyway it doesn't matter. **Here's a workaround.** Just wait until after the hatch section is completed when you are back in the first agent's context, and you can use

```
 ask link-neighbors [ print (word "turtle "  who " has this my-list " my-list) ]
```

and it should work!

```
turtles-own
[
  my-list 
]
to setup
  clear-all

   ;; make turtles to test
   create-turtles 1 [ set my-list [1 2 3 ] ] 
   create-turtles 1 [ set my-list [ ] ] 
   create-turtles 1 [ set my-list [22 33 ] ] 
   create-turtles 1 [ set my-list ["a" "b" "c"] ] 
   create-turtles 1 [ set my-list [3  4 5 ] ] 

    ;; make a network
  ask turtles [ create-links-with other turtles ]


    reset-ticks
end

to go
ask one-of turtles 
  [
    ask link-neighbors [ print (word "turtle "  who " has this my-list " my-list) ]
  ]

  tick

end
```